# How to bind event on parent's element using Angular 2

Tags: angular

I was earlier adding a button element inside child component's template but due to some separation of code, I had to put that button outside of child's template (in parent's template).

I am not sure how to bind `click` event on that button which will eventually trigger a function on child component.

Please suggest.

**Parent:**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 template: `
   <button>Click me to call child's showMe()</button>
   <child></child>
 `
})
```

**Child:**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'child',
 template: `Hi...`
})

class Child {
    public showMe() {
      console.log("ShowMe called...");
    }
   }
```

I don't want to put event binding code in parent's template but want to pass button reference to child component & bind event inside child component itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template variable to reference siblings

```
<button (click)="child.doSomething($event)">click me</button>
<child #child></child>
```

Comment: Thanks..but I am looking for something similar to `@ViewChild` so that I can just pass element id to the child & rest event binding can be done inside the child component itself..

Comment: Please add code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. I'm not able to derive from your explanation how stuff is related.

Comment: I updated my answer. There is no clean way to do this without support from the user of the component (passing a reference explicitly)

Comment: It seems your first answer was much clear. Can you do me a favor by explaining second answer (update)? I am unclear as you are passing child reference inside child component using [button] input binding. I was guessing something to pass button reference on child component i.e. similar to `<child [button]="#button"></child>` & add a variable #button on button element i.e. `<button #button>click me</button>`

Comment: Seems I mixed something up a bit. I updated my answer. With `#child` the button can be referenced from within the template. With `[child]="child"` I pass this reference along to the `@Input() child:Child;` of the `Parent` component. When the button is clicked, the `showMe()` method is called on child.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question. I'm not really sure I understand what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: No..it doesn't answer as don't want to update parent component. Your first answer is fine & answers my question very well..I will continue with that one for now. You can revert update to the point which you provided after I added code. Thanks a lot..